# Require mmap python module

Tags: python, mmap, splunk

We are developing a Splunk based application and use the python 2.7 version available along with Splunk to run python scripts.

We have recently installed another third party API which requires mmap module for execution. However, this module is currently not available in Splunk's python. I read in the splunk forum that we can manually copy this module from a native installation into our python installation and use it.

I am unable to find the module anywhere for download. Can anyone tell me from where i can download this?

Thanks,

Keerthana

Comment: This is a compiled module [see the source](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Modules/mmapmodule.c) and it is built at install time. You need to build it for whatever version of linux splunx is using.

Comment: mmap module is implemented in c and the shared library is present in the path /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/mmap.so , I think the you have to copy this shared object